# FAB doesn't stick to bottom|end when using ViewPager

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, floating-action-button

I'm using a fragment with a ViewPager+TabLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.view.InventoryOverviewFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The ViewPager in turn hosts three different options you can click on (goods received, goods sold, inventory levels). Two of these fragments contain a recyclerView and should have a FAB (goods received and goods sold).

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.view.InventoryReceivedFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewReceived"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addReceived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is supposed to be on the bottom right corner when I test it on my device, however, the FAB is always on the top right corner. As shown in the code, I've also tried using a constraintLayout where the constraints for bottom and end are set, but no luck...

Could someone pls help me out with this? It's driving me crazy ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the ViewPager height to match the constraints wit 0dp, and you didn't add any constraints that controls its height; so add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to the `ViewPager` so that it always has the entire height of the parent so that the underlying tabs will take the entire height as well.

If it didn't work, then make the `ViewPager` height as `match_parent`

Comment: Aaaaaah, what a stupid mistake xD works like a charm now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to give viewpager bottom constraint.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```